# Product is not available with In-App purchase in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-build

I have developed a PhoneGap application with in-app purchases. I used PhoneGap Build for that. But how do I test in-app purchases?

The problem is that every in-app purchase sends an error that the product is not available. Guess it's because the app does not have any contact with the iTunes Connect and my in-app purchase. But how do I get it and work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read the guidelines for in app purchases first. There is already a section about testing IAPs. Sandbox is the one you need, than you can test your IAPs.

[Apple - InApp Purchase Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH1-SW1)